# Highcharts/Highstock with React and Boost not working (very high cpu usage)

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, highcharts-boost

I'm implementing this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/samples/highcharts/boost/line-series-heavy-dynamic/ but with React.

```
import React from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsBoost from 'highcharts/modules/boost'
HighchartsBoost(Highcharts)

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

class Plot extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.n = 20
    this.s = 600
    this.addPoint = this.addPoint.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var series = getSeries(this.n, this.s)

    console.time('line');
    this.chart = Highcharts.chart('hc-container', {
        boost: {
          enabled: true,
          seriesThreshold: 1
        },
        chart: {
            animation: false,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts drawing ' + (this.n * this.s) + ' points across ' + this.s + ' series'
        },
        navigator: {
            xAxis: {
                ordinal: false//,
            },
            yAxis: {
            },
            series: {
                color: null
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            ordinal: false
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Using the Boost module'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            shared: false
        },
        series: series
    });
    console.timeEnd('line');

    setInterval(this.addPoint, 1000);
  }

  addPoint() {
    ++this.n;

    if (!this.chart.series) return 

    this.chart.series.forEach(se => {
        var x = this.n
        var y = 2 * Math.sin(x / 100) + Math.random()

        //Yeah...
        if (se.options.className === "highcharts-navigator-series") {
            return;
        }

        se.addPoint([x, y], false, true, false);
        // se.options.data.push([x, y]);
        // se.options.data.shift();
        // se.isDirty = true;
        // se.isDirtyData = true;
    });

    this.chart.redraw();

  }

  render() {
    return <div id='hc-container' />
  }
}

export default Plot

function getData(n) {
    var arr = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
        arr.push([
            i,
            2 * Math.sin(i / 100) + Math.random()
        ]);
    }
    return arr;
}

function getSeries(n, s) {
    var i = 0,
        r = [];

    for (; i < s; i++) {
        r.push({
            data: getData(n),
            animation: false,
            lineWidth: 2,
            boostThreshold: 1,
            turboThreshold: 1,
            showInNavigator: true,
            requireSorting: false
        });
    }

    return r;
}
```

I don't think boost module is working this way because CPU goes very very high.
I their example (running in chrome) CPU is around 0.x
But in my implementation it goes to 120 most of the time.

Comment: Hi user2806907, Do you use official Highcharts wrapper for React? : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react. Also, could you create live demo with your code, for example like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/rmjw8347po ? It would be much easier to debug and test.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rw6lz551q

Comment: Hi user2806907, your live demo with boost module is working fine for me. In this case react has a negative impact on performance and too much can not be done. You can try disable markers for series. Maybe it's just not worth using reactive in this case?